# OnClick в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
var btn = document.createElement (('v' == '\v') ? 'input name="myName">' : 'input'); btn.name = 'startbutton';
btn.type = 'button';
btn.id = 'startbutton';
btn.value = 'Запуск';
btn.style.cssText = 'color: red; margin-top: 15px; ...';
document.getElementById ('message_form').appendChild (btn);
```

Как прописать в этот код действие кнопки при нажатии (должна выполниться функция `run()` )?
Использование HTML/CSS невозможно. Только JavaScript.

Вопрос закрыт, так как разобрался сам. 
Добавил в код строку:

```
 btn.onclick = function() { run() };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без параметров

```
obj.onclick = myFunc;
```

с параметрами

```
obj.onclick = function() { myFunc(someVar); }
```